# regex limit entering a number greater than 24999999.99

Tags: regex, expression

I am having trouble with this.  I would like to only allow any number from 0 to 24999999.99.   I am new to regular expressions, and am having difficulty with this.

Comment: Why regex? Why not number comparison?

Comment: what language are you working in; why would you use regex instead of "less than" function?

Answer (score 2):

```
^0*(\d{0,7}(\.\d+)?|1\d{7}(\.\d+)?|2[0-4]\d{6}(\.(9([0-8]\d*)?|990*|[0-8]\d*))?)$
```

By way of tutorial, I'll break this down for you:

```
^        Match the beginning of the string
0*       Any number of leading Zeros, including none
(
  \d{0,7}  Zero to seven digits.
  (\.\d+)? An optional decimal followed by one or more digits
  |        OR
  1\d{7}   A one followed by exactly seven digits
  (\.\d+)? The decimal expression again
  |        OR
  2[0-4]   A two, followed by 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4
  \d{6}    ... followed by six digits (exactly)
  (
    \.(      A decimal point, with...
      9        A nine
      (
        [0-8]\d* Any digit except nine, followed by any number of digits
      )?       optionally
      |        OR
      990*     Two nines, followed by any number of zeros
      |        OR
      [0-8]\d* Any number except 9, followed by any number of digits
    )
  )?       This whole decimal expression has been optional
)
$      End of String.
```

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?3749l).

But you're probably better off doing `getFloatValue(str)<24999999.99`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two decimal places are fixed you could match this with:

```
^(?:(?:\d{1,7})|(?:[0-1]\d{1,7})|(?:2[0-4]\d{1,6}))(?:\.\d{2}){0,1}$
```

Here the `^` and trailing `$` make it match a complete string but you could leave them out (problem is it will then match without decimals if someone enters just 1 decimal). `\d` is numeric character and I used the `{m,n}` to say what the minimum and maximum repeats are. The `(?: )` groups the decimal point and decimals together with the `?:` making it a non capturing group since you don't need to capture those values.

Breakdown of the groups:

- `(?:(?:\d{1,7})` - Captures values below 10000000.00
- `(?:[0-1]\d{1,7})` - Captures values below 20000000.00 (thanks to @jkshah for spotting my error in missing that)
- `(?:2[0-4]\d{1,6})` - Captures values above 20000000.00 and check for leading 24
- `(?:\.\d{2}){0,1}` - Captures decimals

Comment: breaks for *15999999.99*

Comment: Dammit :( I hate when that happens

Answer (score 0):

only considering the two decimal points. also, no negative numbers.

```
^[0-2]?[0-4]?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, this can be better handled with mathematical comparison.

But if you must have regex, then try following

```
^(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]{0,6}(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lF1oB5)

Comment: 24999999.991 > 24999999.99

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan True. But when OP says *only allow any number from 0 to 24999999.99*, I can bet on he means *positive numbers less than 25000000*